# ClassNotFoundException on Galaxy Tab (only)

Tags: android, galaxy

I have a working Android application. It works on more than 500 different devices. The manifest is

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="info.decamps.droid.photoid" android:versionCode="5"
android:versionName="1.4">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_label"
    android:name="PhotoIDroid" android:description="@string/app_desc"
    android:debuggable="FALSE">
```

But when it it launched from a Samsung Galaxy Tab, it doesn't start and crashes with:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
>   instantiate application
>   info.decamps.droid.photoid.PhotoIDroid:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   info.decamps.droid.photoid.PhotoIDroid
>   in loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/info.decamps.droid.photoid-1.apk]
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.makeApplication(ActivityThread.java:670)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4483)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$3000(ActivityThread.java:135)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2181)
>   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
>   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
>   Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>   at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
>   Method) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   info.decamps.droid.photoid.PhotoIDroid
>   in loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/info.decamps.droid.photoid-1.apk]
>   at
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
>   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
>   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:945)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.makeApplication(ActivityThread.java:660)
>   ... 11 more

How an the Samsung Galaxy not find the application class?
Any clue on how to resolve this?

I have been able to reproduce tis crash on the Samsung Galaxy emulator.

Comment: @rds: What is the superclass of `info.decamps.droid.photoid.PhotoIDroid`?

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm not sure I understand your question. I have not developed this class, it is the [`Application`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class generated by Android from the manifest. From the doc, "here is normally no need to subclass Application."

Comment: @rds: The exception is being raised because Android cannot load `info.decamps.droid.photoid.PhotoIDroid`. This is a class. Classes in Java have superclasses. What is the superclass of `info.decamps.droid.photoid.PhotoIDroid`?

Comment: I had this same issue when I installed the new SDK and my extended Application class was in a library project.  To fix it I removed the library project and re-added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed the [`android:name`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#nm) attribute declaration from the `AndroidManifest.xml` and it now works.

Comment: That basically means it is no longer using your custom `Application` class. If that works for you, cool. If not, since the superclass (`Application`) presumably is there, check out static initializers and the like, to see what you are asking for that might be missing.

Comment: Thanks, but I did not write any custom Application class. It seems most mobiles (and the emulator) ignore the `android:name` if the class does not exist. Maybe, it was added recently in the API (hence ignored by old devices)

Comment: android:name has been there since 1.0, and should always crash the app if the specified class can't be found.  Strange.

Comment: You're right @hackbod, that's strange. Yet, I created a new "Hello world" scaffold in Eclipse, changed `<string name="app_name">hello world</string>` and `android:name="@string/app_name"` and it honestly works in the emulator. Should this be considered as a bug?

Comment: @rds: Or maybe it might be a case of relative path. Have you tried declaring **PhotoIDroid** as `android:name=".PhotoIDroid"` since I'm assuming this class is found relative to the package `info.decamps.droid.photoid`. If not, declare it relative to this package.